# С прописной или со строчной начинается прямая речь, цитируемая не с начала предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, кавычки, цитата

Господь спас блудницу от разъяренной толпы словами: «…*кто из вас без греха, первый брось на нее камень*» (Ин. 8: 7).

- В оригинале "кто из вас без греха" – это не начало предложения, слова эти стоят после двоеточия. Если важно привести не только цитату (на нее указывает курсив), но и передать эти слова именно как прямую речь, приходится прибегнуть к кавычкам. Однако вопрос в том, может ли прямая речь начинаться в подобном виде "многоточие, строчная буква – ибо это еще и цитата, требующая своих правил оформления".
- Если да, как бы пример посмотреть? Если нет, что предпочесть: по правилам оформленная прямая речь или по правилам оформленная цитата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду синоидальный перевод?

> Когда же продолжали спрашивать Его, Он, восклонившись, сказал им: кто из вас без греха, первый брось на неё камень.

Во многих других переводах прямая речь начинается со слова *кто* и пишется в кавычках с прописной буквы ([Сравнение переводов: От Иоанна 8:7](https://bible.by/verse/43/8/7/)). Это больше соответствует современной грамматике.

У вас публицистика или научный труд? Если первое, то я бы не усложнял и цитировал бы речь Иисуса как полное предложение:

**Господь спас блудницу от разъяренной толпы словами: «Кто из вас без греха, первый брось на нее камень» (Ин. 8: 7).**

Об оформлении цитат можно прочесть здесь: [Какие знаки препинания используются при цитировании?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76)

Пример из того же источника:

> Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»

Дополнение.

Если хотите быть ближе к стилю первоисточника, то по-моему, так:

**Господь спас блудницу от разъяренной толпы словами: кто из вас без греха, первый брось на нее камень (Ин. 8: 7).**

Примечание: По-моему, нужно исходить из того, что вы цитируете не Евангелие, а Иисуса (на основе того, как его слова переданы в Евангелии).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможны два варианта:

а) Прямая речь: Господь спас блудницу от разъяренной толпы, сказав: «Кто из вас без греха, первый брось на нее камень».

При цитировании используется строчная буква, если сама цитата приводится не с начала.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=167#pp167

б) Несогласованное определение: Господь спас блудницу от разъяренной толпы словами «Кто из вас без греха, первый брось на нее камень».

http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxxi.html

Примечание. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но перед ними двоеточие не ставится, например: Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Он вспомнил пословицу «Не плюй в колодец…» и отошёл в сторону; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Comment: Можно и как элемент предложения, но можно и как как цитату с двоеточием (Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!» )

Comment: В вашем примере двоеточие  обозначает предупредительную паузу. А в приведенном предложении эта пауза как-то не на месте, получается, что спас словами,  а дальше идет уточнение, какими именно. А без двоеточия "словами" является всего лишь приложением к дословному высказыванию.

Comment: Возмите пример с главой. По- Вашему, там говорится, что глава заканчивается словами, а  дальше идет уточнение, какими именно?

Comment: Глава всегда заканчивается словами, поэтому пауза  предупреждает  о том, что далее следует пояснение, какими именно словами.

Comment: Не буду отрицать, что в Ваших словах что-то есть, но Вы замечаете разницу, которая, я думаю, остается незаметной для других, то есть практически не имеет значения. Вот еще пример из Нацкорпуса: *Встречая новый год, мы друг друга приветствуем словами: "С новым годом, с новым счастьем! [митрополит Антоний (Блум). Новогодний молебен (1988)]*  Пусть глава всегда заканчивается словами, но приветствовать можно не только словами.

Comment: То же самое. Можно точно сказать, что в конце фразы будет приветствовать "словами" (а не жестами).  А вот спасать словами не часто приходится.